# Best way to handle data in Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

What is the best way to handle data in a project reactor?

using flatMap:

```
public Mono<User> flat() {
    return this.repository.findByName("Jeff")
      .flatMap(
        user -> {
          user.setInfo(new UserInfo("Palo Alto/CA", "Safari", "h1alexbel/transformed"));
          return Mono.just(user);
        }
      );
  }
```

handle:

```
public Mono<User> handle() {
    return this.repository.findByName("Jeff")
      .handle(
        (user, sink) ->
          user.setInfo(
            new UserInfo("Palo Alto/CA", "Safari", "h1alexbel/transformed")
          )
      );
  }
```

or something else?

As far I understand, `handle` helps to combine 2 operations together: `flatMap`
and `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest analog of the `handle` is a `map` (not `flatMap`). You could think about it as a combination of the `map` & `filter`. In contrast to `flatMap` both `handle` and `map` are synchronous function.

**`map`** - transforms the emitted item by applying a synchronous function. It provides 1:1 mapping and **every** item should be mapped. The only way to skip item is to throw exception and then immediately handle the error signal using `onErrorResume`.

**`handle`** - is more flexible and provides 0 or 1 mapping. It's possible to skip items by not emitting signal using `sink.next()`.

In your case there is no reason to wrap user into `Mono` and use `flatMap`. Use `map` because mapping is 1:1.