# What is the difference between .handle() and .map()?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have the following code which I've written using `.handle()` and `.map()`, which both seem to work for my use case, but I'd like to understand precisely why I should choose one over the other.

**.handle()**

```java
Flux.fromIterable(persons)
    .handle((person, sink) -> {
        try {
            stopProcessingStuff(person);
            disconnectPerson(person);
            sink.next(new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.SUCCESS, person.id()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            sink.next(new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.FAILURE, person.id()));
        }
    })
```

**.map()**

```java
Flux.fromIterable(persons)
    .map(b -> {
        try {
            stopProcessingStuff(person);
            disconnectPerson(person);
            return new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.SUCCESS, person.id());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.FAILURE, person.id());
        }
    })
```

Comment: `map` transforms the input and returns a new value, `handle` consumes its input and doesn't produce a new value

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75386970/5133585)

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#map-java.util.function.Function-, https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#handle-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

Answer (score 1):

As much as they are extremely similar, they have different purposes and behaviors:

1. `.map()`:

   - **Purpose**: The `map()` method is used for **transforming the elements of a stream** from one type to another by applying a given function to each element of the stream.
   - **Return Type**: It returns a new stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to each element of the original stream.
   - **Usage**: This is useful when you want to transform the elements of a stream without altering the original elements.

   In your code:

   ```java
   Flux.fromIterable(persons)
       .map(b -> {
           try {
               stopProcessingStuff(person);
               disconnectPerson(person);
               // Transforming the elements
               return new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.SUCCESS, person.id());
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // Transforming the elements
               return new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.FAILURE, person.id());
           }
       })
   ```
2. `.handle()`:

   - **Purpose**: The `handle()` method allows you to **consume** each element of the stream, **but not necessarily produce or create elements**. However, it also allows you to produce additional elements to the resulting stream or even terminate the stream early by using a different type of `Consumer`.
   - **Return Type**: It returns a new stream that may contain different elements based on the function applied.The function passed to `handle()` takes two parameters: the first parameter represents the input element, and the second parameter is a `BiConsumer` that can be used to add elements to the resulting stream.
   - **Usage**: `handle()` can be helpful when you need to perform a more complex transformation on elements and may generate multiple elements for each input element.

   In your code:

   ```java
   Flux.fromIterable(persons)
       .handle((person, sink) -> {
           try {
               stopProcessingStuff(person);
               disconnectPerson(person);
               sink.next(new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.SUCCESS, person.id()));
           }
           catch (Exception ex) {
               sink.next(new DisconnectPersonResponse(Status.FAILURE, person.id()));
           }
       })
   ```

In summary, **`.map()` is used for straightforward one-to-one transformations** of elements in a stream, whereas **`.handle()` is more versatile** and allows you to create more complex transformations, produce additional elements, or even terminate the stream conditionally.